# Getting "java.io.EOFException" after sending a file throught socket

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream, eofexception

I'm trying to implement basic communication through sockets, what I have now is:

- server start's to listen on socket,

  ```
  this.serverSocket_ = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort_);
  clientSocket = this.serverSocket_.accept();
  ```
- client connects, and server starts separate thread to operate with that client,
- both open Object output and input streams,

  ```
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket_.getOutputStream());
  out.flush();
  in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket_.getInputStream());
  ```
- client sends two i Doubles, String and Long over that stream (flushes after each one),

  ```
      out.writeObject(conf_);
      out.flush();
      out.writeObject(supp_);
      out.flush();
      out.writeObject(separator_);
      out.flush();
      out.writeObject(new Long(dataFile_.length()));
      out.flush();
  ```
- server succesfully receives those objects over previously opened streams,

  ```
  conf_ = (Double) in_.readObject();
  supp_ = (Double) in_.readObject();
  separator_ = (String) in_.readObject();
  fileSize_ = (Long) in_.readObject();
  ```
- and now "the hard part",
- clients wants to send a file so opens different output stream (not object output stream) and sends the file,

  ```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dataFile_);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  OutputStream os = clientSocket_.getOutputStream();

  while (current < fileSize) {
      bytesRead = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      if (bytesRead >= 0) {
          os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
          current += bytesRead;
      }
      progressBar_.setValue(current);
      progressBar_.repaint();
  }
  os.flush();
  ```
- the server receives the file (also uses simple input stream instead ObjectInputStream),

  ```
  int bytesRead;
  int current = 0;

  tmpFile_ = File.createTempFile("BasketAnalysis", "rec.dat");

  byte[] mybytearray = new byte[fileSize];
  InputStream is = clientSocket_.getInputStream();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile_);
  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
  bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  current = bytesRead;

  do {
      bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
      (mybytearray.length - current));
      if (bytesRead >= 0)
          current += bytesRead;

  } while ((bytesRead > -1) && (current < fileSize));

  bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
  bos.flush();
  bos.close();
  ```
- so far everything works fine, file is received, but now server performs some time consuming processing on that file after which sends response with whe results to client,

  ```
  String resp = new String("Some processing result...");
  out_.writeObject(resp);
  out_.flush();
  ```
- the client is supposed to receive the result what finishes the whole communication,

  ```
  String message = (String) in.readObject();
  Console.info("server > " + message);
  ```

Unfortunately, that last step on client side fails with exception:

```
    java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at basketAnalysis.client.Client.run(Client.java:74)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I want client to block on waiting for server response after sending the file, but it suddenly finishes with the exception after sending the file. I am pretty sure that I do something wrong with switching between simple streams and Object streams.

Does anybody know what should I change to haave it working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Aren't you getting an exception on the server side when you `out_.writeObject(resp);` for the final message?

Comment: Nope. Actually server doesn't finish it's processing because client disconnects what causes an exception on server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your basic misunderstanding is here:

> clients wants to send a file so opens different output stream
>
> ```
> OutputStream os = clientSocket_.getOutputStream();
> ```

That doesn't open a *different* output stream - that will get another reference to the *same* output stream which you've already got wrapped in the `ObjectOutputStream`. If you want two streams of data, you'll need to open two separate connections.